# Google map is grey when it is loaded How can i fix it?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have added a button which retrieve my current location
when i click that button it returns my location but the map is always grey in color,nothing else is displayed

Comment: Please check your map key. It is wrong thats why your map is not showing. Go to Google console and get a new key and check again. It will help you.

Comment: Its the api key problem, did you by any chance use the androidhive places api example? If yes its api v1 and its no longer supported

Comment: still same problem,ive check the api key

Comment: Can you post some of code it I can test on? and also please read here http://javapapers.com/android/show-map-in-android/ Step by step, it will show the map

Comment: I dont know how but it has start working

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your key. Probably you are using the key from API version 1 and code for version 2 (using SupportmapFragment or Mapfragment), this is why you might be getting a grey map with grids on it.

Please get a new from Developers console for Google maps version 2.

Hope this would help!!!